# Why do I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, exc-bad-access

I have following code, which executes on button press. At first it works as expected but second time onwards application hangs and I get **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** signal.

```
- (IBAction) comicDetailsPressed:(id)sender {
   static IssueProperties *props = nil;
    if (props == nil) {
        props = [ComicDataParser 
         parseComicForUrl:@"http://dummy.com/Jan.xml"];
    }

    NSLog(@"%d", [props totalPages]);

    totalPages.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [props totalPages]]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what line it's crashing on, which will mean answers will have to be speculative.

You have a static pointer to a `IssueProperties` object, but when you assign to it, you aren't using `retain`. You probably should.

This is assuming that the return value from `parseComicForUrl:` is a `IssueProperties` object or a subclass.

I'm assuming that the `text` property is an `NSString` set to `copy` and not `retain`. If not, it should be.

Comment: Your statement about the `text` property seems like overengineering. While you should copy string properties that could come from any client code, in this case we can only see the property being set by `+stringWithFormat:`, which returns an immutable string. Therefore copy is overkill unless you know something about Prashant's code that we don't.

Comment: @Graham Lee I don't understand how you see it as overengineering; you have to choose either `assign`, `retain` or `copy` for a property, and it's well-known the issues you get with `NSString` properties when you don't use `copy`... so why not avoid future issues and reduce risk if you can?

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: Ya Aint Gonna Need It. If you try to avoid all the future issues you can think of, you'll never ship 1.0.

Comment: @Graham Lee You're overstating your case about overengineering. As if mentioning the best practice of using `copy` with `NSString` properties is akin to telling the guy he'll never ship his app. Let's dial back the hyperbole a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to retain the object you get back from `+parseComicForUrl:`. Also, why don't you use an instance variable for `props`?

Comment: making props as an instance variable is good idea, I was just trying some XML parsing thing in objective-c, so I did not think of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without a lot more context, it is going to be impossible to answer for sure, but my first thought would be this:

your `static IssueProperties *props` would not be nil the second time around.  Instead, it would have the value that `[ComicDataParser parseComicForUrl]` returned.

My guess is that the `ComicDataParser` is `autorelease`ing the response, and so the second time around you have a pointer that is not nil, but is now pointing to an already `release`d object, which is invalid.

If I am right, you need a `retain` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, problem is fixed after retaining `props`. I think I should go through Memory management guide again.